# Unable to delete local registry images in GKE

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

For the list of docker images that is displayed in GKE, I am trying to delete unwanted ones in my GKE console but getting error.

As suggested in this link https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/delete
I am trying to run it but getting error.

For example, I am tring to delete mynginx image.

```
xxx@cloudshell:~ (involuted-ratio-227118)$ gcloud container images delete mynginx --force-delete-tags --quiet
ERROR: (gcloud.container.images.delete) [mynginx:latest] digest must be of the form "sha256:<digest>".
```

```
xxx@cloudshell:~ (involuted-ratio-227118)$ gcloud container images delete --quiet cs-6000-devshell-vm-37ed1cd7-726d-48bc-85df-8ce82c65f035/involuted-ratio-227118/mynginx@DIGEST
ERROR: (gcloud.container.images.delete) [cs-6000-devshell-vm-37ed1cd7-726d-48bc-85df-8ce82c65f035/involuted-ratio-227118/mynginx@DIGEST] digest must be of the form "sha256:<digest>".
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/delete#IMAGE_NAME),

> "The fully qualified name(s) of image(s) to delete. The name(s) should
>   be formatted as *.gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE_PATH@sha256:DIGEST or
>   *.gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE_PATH:TAG."

The image names must be in the above format. Also, you need to replace the word DIGEST with the image's sha256 digest. You can get the digest using command like

```
docker images --digests | grep {IMAGE NAME}
```

Where {IMAGE NAME} is the name of the image. Documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/).

Comment: Great.
- summary:
`gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/your-project-id/hello-app`
then `gcloud container images delete gcr.io/your-project-id/hello-app@sha256:yourDIGEST --quiet`